# Add an extra heading at the top of table that spans all columns but still allows the table to be sorted on the second row of headings

Tags: jquery, html-table, tablesorter

I'm stumped again. I have tried (all day yesterday) to no avail.

I want to add an extra heading at the top of [this table](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-sort-list.html/) that spans all columns but still allows the table to be sorted on the second row of headings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to disable the sort of the spanned column because the original tablesorter has some issues with sorting the columns below it.

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    headers: {
        0: { sorter: false } // disable first column
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could try out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/). [This demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-header-column-span.html) shows that you can use the spanned header to sort all of the columns below it.